# Why does my laptop overheat on 14.04?

Tags: drivers, overheating

I have read similar posts here but could not find an answer that solves my problem. So here is what happens: As soon as i open one app in Ubuntu 14.04 my laptop overheats making noise .
Laptop specs are : Intel Corei5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.50 GHz, RAM 4GB, Nvidia Geforce GT 630M 1GB.

I am aware of the project called bumblebee , i have installed it (using the cmd: `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`) but nothing changes.
I am also aware of `nvidia-prime` , installed it but still nothing changed.

Can you suggest a possible solution ? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it brand new or is it full of dust? had similar problems in Windows on my laptop...

Comment: @Alvar It is kinda new actually ... but i will check it for dust , thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: What is the app that causes it to overheat? Or is it all apps?

Comment: I tried to fix mine (Intel i7 + Intel HD 4500 Graphics) and the real problem is Unity Desktop, It is not lightwight enough, in every new version it is getting a little better but still not good enough as the classic desktop, gnome 3 or the kde. I hope Canonical Devs will fix this and finally concentrate on flat design.

Answer (score 2):

You can install indicator-cpufreq to adjust the cpu to a lower frequency.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Use CTRL + F2 to open a run dialog and enter the command:

```
indicator-cpufreq
```

to start it up the first time and it should auto start at boot after that.

Also, make sure you have all the sensor apps installed

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp libsensors4 xsensors
```

and run the following command to detect the sensors

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Follow the recommendations closely just **don't do anything risky** and you'll be fine.

To show the temps in realtime use the following command:

```
watch -n 1 -d sensors
```

Also, you can install the prime-indicator to help you manually select the graphic card

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

And check out this post from webupd8 concerning nvidia-prime on 14.04. http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html

source http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

Finally, you might find this helpful http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html

Comment: I have followed the steps above but my laptop still overheats when i open apps like firefox, software center, and sometimes office...
Maybe because i have both nvidia-prime and bumblebee installed ?
Should i unistall some of those ? Thanks for the detailed answer !

Comment: @user308137 have you checked the actual temps? the only other thing I can think of is switch to intel for firefox and use VAAPI with VDPAU http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/adobe-flash-player-hardware.html after install, switch to intel driver and execute `VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox` to run firefox. It's supposed to cut cpu usage because of support for accelerated decoding.

Comment: @user308137 allot of people don't actually check the temps and when they do, report regular operating temps for their processor(s). Another aspect to take into consideration is that, even if you are using windows 7 or 8 x86_64, most of the time, you are actually only running the 32 bit version of any given program on a 64bit *capable* operating system. Take firefox for instance, which is not even available for windows in 64bit form unless you use "firefox nightly" . It may be that you're not used to fully utilizing  your processor(s) because you were only running 32bit applications but now 64.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is solved ! Here is what i did after a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04:

1) sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331
2) sudo apt-get update
3) sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
4) Run indicator-cpufreq (like said above).

Thank you all for putting the time and effort to help !

Answer (score 0):

if your laptop has Nvidia chipset, this next lines may help you,
I was having heat problems when watching any video through the internet o any local video player, cause the computer was overheating a lot, even with external cooler pads,
so I search for many suggestions and finally one solution brought coolness to the coreI7 laptop which actually has a GeForce graphics card within

the link is this...

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html

but you should check it out before do anything
but
 the resumed process is here...

Install Nvidia-Prime in Ubuntu 13.10 or 14.04

Follow the instructions below only if you know what you're doing and how to revert the changes in case LightDM fails to start, etc.!

Update: the instructions below should work under Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr too.

Note: the  nvidia-prime package only supports the proprietary Nvidia drivers and won't work with Nouveau!

If you're using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander or 14.04 Trusty Tahr and want to test the Optimus support in the Nvidia Graphics Drivers 319.12+, here's what you need to do:

1. Firstly, purge Bumblebee if installed:
   sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*

Also, make sure libvdpau-va-gl1 is not enabled system-wide because it causes Nvidia Settings to crash on start - if it is, either disable it or simply remove the package:
sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1

2. Install the proprietary Nvidia drivers and the Nvidia Prime package:
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
3. Reboot the system.

That's it, after a reboot, your laptop should be using the Nvidia GPU to render the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Now my laptop is cooling itself. I just installed:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia indicator-cpufreq
reboot
apt list --installed | grep -i nvidia
bumblebee-nvidia/xenial,now 3.2.1-10 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-304/xenial,now 304.131-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-current/xenial,now 304.131-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-304/xenial,now 304.131-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/xenial,now 361.42-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```